# Rails: Empty params when do ajax post with content-type = application/json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, parameters

I used Backbone as Javascript framework for my new project. However, When I invoke save() on a Model , Rails server just can't parse it to the params hash

Javascript

```
user new Project.Models.User({email : "nqtien310@gmail.com"})
user.save()
```

Rails server

```
puts params
=> {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"users"}

puts request.raw_post
=> "{\"email\":\"nqtien310@gmail.com\"}"
```

Then I tried to set Backbone.emulateJSON to true

Javascript

```
Backbone.emulateJSON = true
```

and Rails can parse the post data to params now, but not the expected data

```
puts params
=> {"model"=>"{\"email\":\"nqtien310@gmail.com\"}", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"users"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a long research , I figure it out that inside of my profiles' initialize/mime_types.rb , they added

```
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :mobile
```

Dig into a bit , I can see that Rails uses the mime types to parse the request body , in this case , application/json is overriden , and Rails can't use the Json parse strategy to parse the request body into params hash, that's why it's empty

Backbone.emulateJSOn will set another content-type instead of application/json, that's why Rails still can understand this Mime Type, and has correspond parse strategy for it , but since it's not the JSON strategy , so the params is not in JSON format

Json parse strategy ( from Rails source )

```
when :json
      data = request.deep_munge ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body)
      request.body.rewind if request.body.respond_to?(:rewind)
      data = {:_json => data} unless data.is_a?(Hash)
      data.with_indifferent_access
```